# Regarding finite simple groups of type $^2D_n$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, simple-groups, maximal-subgroup

I would like to known if is there any list (even partial) of (maximal) subgroups of a finite simple group of type $^2D_n$ ($n>3$). I tried to search on Google and MathSciNet, but it seems either there is nothing or I used the wrong keywords. Is there such a list?

Comment: You could try searching for maximal subgroups of finite classical groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These groups are orthogonal of type $O^-$. A recent, quite explicit, description of the maximal subgroups can be found in:
Holt, Roney-Dougal: Constructing maximal subgroups of orthogonal groups.
LMS J. Comput. Math. 13, 164-191 (2010)

Link:
[https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/papers/maxorthoggps/maxorth.pdf](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emareg/download/papers/maxorthoggps/maxorth.pdf)

Comment: In  the paper, we only describe the construction of the maximal subgroups of geometric type, which can be done generally for all groups of this type. We do not describe those in the Aschbacher class $\mathcal{S}$ (i.e. groups that are almost simple mod scalars, act absolutely irreducibly, and cannot be defined over a proper subfield). The groups in this class have been enumerated up to degree $16$ (i.e. $n=8$).